# After installing ADT plugin for Eclipse I'm unable to open an android app project

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, windows-8, eclipse-plugin

I have JDK 1.6 version installed on my pc(Windows 8 64-bit system). 
I installed Eclipse ADT + Android SDK package from the site.
But after installing the developer tools and installing ADT plugin as directed in the site given below... ***http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html*** , , I restarted eclipse but was unable to see the Android Welcome window.

I tried opening a new Android Application Project but after I finished clicking the final "Finish" button , 
It gave me an error... saying 
"***Loading data for Android L(Preview) has encountered a problem. Parsing data for Android L failed.Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.*** " 
I'm unable to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use 1.7 JRE. That should fix the problem.

Comment: I tried installing jre 1.7 but it didnt work. I get the same error message which I mentioned previously @Sasikanth

Comment: Is your eclipse using the 1.7 JRE? Update your eclipse.ini to use the 1.7 JRE and check installed JREs as well - add the 1.7 JRE there and set it to default if it isn't